# MySQL Incrementing value until it is unique in single query

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a way to increment a value until it is unique in a single MySQL query?

Say you have a table that records the Unix Timestamp in microtime and you want to insert a row but you can the microtime to be incremented until it is a unique time. In a single query, is that possible?

In pseudocode, something like (using PHP):

```
INSERT INTO items (time) VALUES (WHILE((SELECT COUNT(*) WHERE time={$newValue})>0,time = time+0.000001));
```

I know the pseudocode doesn't work, but hopefully, it illustrates approximately what I'd like to do.

Comment: Wouldn't an auto-increment key be better, then you can just record the time as it is.  This allows several things to happen at the same time, but you can still work out which one was first.

Comment: Sounds like a really bad idea that could lead to race conditions. Combine your microtime with an auto-increment column and you should never have a problem.

Comment: I see. That's a good point. I thought it may be a little simpler, but race conditions would be an issue.

Comment: Yes, you don't want the microtime to be a *key.*

Answer (score 0):

Here's a general strategy that will do it:

- First, be sure that you're not using the microtime as a primary key ... *(that's not related to the following – it's just good practice)*

Now:

1. `BEGIN TRANSACTION`  (with a suitable isolation level)
2. `SELECT MAX(microtime) FROM` ... to find the largest value now stored.
3. `INSERT` ... with a suitable time.
4. `COMMIT`

Transactions, properly used, will cause steps #1-4 to be *atomic.*  You can do steps #2 and #3 knowing that no race will occur.  You can do as many operations in "step #3" as you wish, and *all of them* will happen at once.  (Or, if you instead `ROLLBACK`, *none* of them did.)